# Is there any way to find out if localForage/indexedDb is processing data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localforage

So I have this webapp, and I am using the async localForage (angular localForage to be specific). Now, I want to warn the user if he tries to close the browser window while there are still some localForage operations going on.

I know at least the browser knows, because in Firefox if I do close the window, it gives me a warning (albeit after I open a window again) that some indexedDb operations were cancelled (localForage uses indexedDb).

Comment: if anyone's interested, the wrapper I made is open source and can be found [here](https://github.com/Eyra-is/Eyra/blob/master/Frontend/da-webapp/src/services/myLocalForage.service.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing similar to that is available, but you can wrap `localForage` with a custom service that

1. sets a special flag once an operation with `localForage` is initiated
2. releases the flag in the callback (once the operation is completed)

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier way, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit tricky because I don't know any "IsBusy" function to use with localForage or even IndexedDB. A suitable solution can be devised ad-hoc to check whether a single operation has finished or not. This can also be adopted as a full scale monitor for all of your localForage async operations.

For example:

```
function cbFunc(err, value) {
                    // Run this code once the value has been
                    // loaded from the offline store.
                    console.log(value);

                    DBWrapper.numCurrOps--;
                    if (DBWrapper.numCurrOps === 0)
                        DBWrapper.isBusy = false;
}

    var DBWrapper = {
            isBusy: false,
            numCurrOps: 0,
            getItem: function(key, cbFunc){
                DBWrapper.isBusy = true;
                DBWrapper.numCurrOps++;
                localforage.getItem('somekey', cbFunc);     
            }

        };
```

This is an example for a wrapper that can help you decide if there is at least one running async operation in the background waiting to finish. You can add more functions to the singleton object  and make them change the "isBusy" property as well.